# How to install Kafka inside a docker image?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am working on docker for the first time where I am trying to run my pyspark code on a docker container.
This my project structure.
[image]

My Dockerfile content:

```
from gcr.io/datamechanics/spark:platform-3.1-dm14

ENV PYSPARK_MAJOR_PYTHON_VERSION=3
WORKDIR /opt/application/

RUN wget  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.5.jar
RUN mv postgresql-42.2.5.jar /opt/spark/jars

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY main.py .
COPY tweepy_kafka_producer.py .
COPY kafka_spark.py .
```

docker-compose.yml file content:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  spark-worker:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
```

I am trying to read tweets using tweepy library, send them to Kafka & read data from Kafka using Spark streaming. All this is running fine on my local and I trying to learn how can I run the same on a docker container. To do that, I have created a docker container and installed libraries from my requriements.txt file using below commands:

```
curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-spark/master/docker-compose.yml
docker build -f Dockerfile -t sparkcontainer .
```

My requirements.txt file contains only four packages: `pyspark, kafka, python-kafka & tweepy`

I started the docker image using the steps below (8558b79243f8 is my docker image name):

```sh
docker run -i -t 8558b79243f8 /bin/bash
```

I do `ls` and these are the files I see:

```
185@f4a100a4ad06:/opt/application$ ls
kafka_spark.py  main.py  requirements.txt  tweepy_kafka_producer.py
```

When I try to run the python file that pushes data into a kafka topic:

```
185@f4a100a4ad06:/opt/application$ python tweepy_kafka_producer.py
```

I see the below error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweepy_kafka_producer.py", line 40, in <module>
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 381, in __init__
    client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, metric_group_prefix='producer',
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 900, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

I understand that I have to install Kafka in the docker image.
Could anyone let me know how can I configure Kafka inside my docker image ?

Comment: You need to run it in a separate container; you will probably also need a ZooKeeper container.  [Kafka setup with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045590/kafka-setup-with-docker-compose) has some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka and Spark are distributed processes; and its a bad practice to use more than one process inside a Docker container.

Instead, add more services to your existing Docker Compose file, copied from existing Docker Compose setups from Kafka.

> My requirements.txt file contains only four packages: pyspark, kafka, python-kafka & tweepy

You don't need two Kafka dependencies ; you only need `pyspark` and `tweepy` since Spark can write to Kafka on its own.

Or you could create a 5th (if counting Zookeeper), for a plain Python container with your producer application that has no Spark dependencies